# Вызов функции из другой функции

Tags: c#, unity3d, update

Есть две функции

```
void Update () 
{
    float input_x = MovementJoystick.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float input_y = MovementJoystick.GetAxis("Vertical");
    bool isWalking = (Mathf.Abs(input_x) + Mathf.Abs(input_y)) > 0;

    anim.SetBool("isWalking", isWalking);
    if (isWalking) 
    {
        anim.SetFloat("x", input_x);
        anim.SetFloat("y", input_y);

        transform.position+=new Vector3(input_x, input_y, 0).normalized*playerSpeed*Time.deltaTime;

    }
}
```

и

```
void fastRun()
{
    playerSpeed = 12;
}
```

Они находятся в одном скрипте. Мне нужно как-то в `void fastRun` вызвать `void Update`, но с другим значением playerSpeed. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: А почему бы не добавить в `Update` аргумент?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`playerSpeed` у вас, судя по всему, поле класса.

Метод `Update` всегда использует актуальное (текущее) значение `playerSpeed`. Т.е. чтобы вызвать его "с другим значением", нужно просто присвоить это значение `playerSpeed`, а после вызова - вернуть оригинальное:

Т.е. вам нужно что-то вроде

```
void fastRun()
{
    var temp = playerSpeed;
    playerSpeed = другое значение;
    Update();
    playerSpeed = temp;
}
```

Хотя, если честно, скорее всего у вас просто надо вызвать Update:

```
void fastRun()
{
    playerSpeed = 12;
    Update();
}
```

Comment: Ну, хм. Первое решение как-то слишком выглядит костылём. Ну и если уж костыль, то почему не `finally { playerSpeed = temp; }`? Второе, судя по всему, правильное.

Comment: @VladD костыль потому что костыль :( на самом деле стоило бы наверное параметром передать, но не до конца понятно чего ж топикастеру хочется

Comment: Ну это да, для такого вопроса есть жёсткая необходимость в хрустальном шаре.

Comment: @PashaPash♦, второй вариант вполне работает, и делал же также, но вот что-то проверить не удосужился, думал, что это не будет  работать. А все оказалось так просто.